# Listview click on item another view visible below that item and on another click it collapse

Tags: android, listview

I am using `Listview` I want when I click on one item of `Listview` and another view expand and when I click on another item the previously clicked item collapse
I want my selected position is true and rest are false I am using list of Boolean type it works like expanded list view

here my adapter class code where I perform on click

```
public class CurrentAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    private ArrayList<Boolean> booleanList;
    private  boolean show=false;
    private String lastSelectPos;

    public CurrentAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context=context;
        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        booleanList = new ArrayList<Boolean>(10);
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            booleanList.add(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return booleanList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final LinearLayout linearLayoutTop,linearLayoutBottom;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item_cuurent, viewGroup, false);
        linearLayoutTop = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ll_current);
        linearLayoutBottom = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ll_current_sub);
        linearLayoutTop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(lastSelectPos==null){
                    lastSelectPos = String.valueOf(position);
                }else {
                    Integer lastPos = Integer.parseInt(lastSelectPos);
                    if(lastPos!=position){
                        booleanList.set(lastPos, false);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
                booleanList.set(position, !booleanList.get(position));
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        if(booleanList.get(position)){
            linearLayoutBottom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else {
            linearLayoutBottom.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could have used ExpandableListView and for closing previous selected you can do it on onGroupClickListener by saving previous selection position.

Comment: but want this in list view basically i want that my selected position is true and un selected become false

Comment: I don't see issue in your adapter code. Have you debugged and check if onClick is being called or not?

Comment: yes i did on click is working but thing is that i want selected position become true and rest item false